# Mathematical proof for virtual particle can be an off-shell particle

Tags: quantum-field-theory, momentum, conservation-laws, propagator, virtual-particles

We have the Feynman propagator$(x^0>y^0)$
as
$$\Delta_F(x-y)=\int {d^4p\over2\pi^4}\frac{\imath}{p_\mu p^\mu-m^2}e^{-\imath p\cdot(x-y)},$$ integrating through the $p^0$ with the help of contour integration will give

$$\Delta_F(x-y)=\int {d^3p\over2\pi^3}\frac{1}{2E_p}e^{-\imath p\cdot(x-y)}$$
Where $E_p=\sqrt{{\bf p^2}-m^2}$.

If we take the Feynman propagator$(x^0>y^0)$ as

$$\Delta_F(x-y)=\int {d^4p\over2\pi^4}\delta({p_\mu p^\mu-m^2})\Theta(k^0)e^{-\imath p\cdot(x-y)}=\int {d^3p\over2\pi^3}\frac{1}{2E_p}e^{-\imath p\cdot(x-y)},$$

The Delta function($\delta({p_\mu p^\mu-m^2})$) implies the particles associated with the Feynman propagator $(x^0>y^0)$  fall on On-shell.
Then why the virtual particles associated with the propagator is termed as Off-shell?

To become an off-shell particle, I think the mass need to vary, but there is no integral over mass and we can fix the mass and can vary $p^0$ and $\bf p$ over the mass shell. so anyone please give a mathematical proof that virtual particle can be off-shell?

Comment: Your integration of the Feynman propagator is correct -- you've implicitly assumed that $x^0 > y^0$.

Comment: Yeah, It's the matter of flipping the contour in the upper and lower half-planes, the real question here is regarding the virtual particles and it's Mass shell connections, could you give some comments regarding this? @Zack

Comment: Oops, I made a typo -- I meant to say that your integration is INcorrect!

Comment: Where it is?@Zack

Comment: The two functions are clearly different: while the first integral solves the wave equation $(\partial^2+m^2)\Delta_F(x-y)\propto\delta(x-y)$, the second solves $(\partial^2+m^2)\Delta_F(x-y)=0$. (Because $a\times 1/a=1$ and $a\times \delta(a)=0$.)

Comment: Could you please write,  between which step the integration has an error? if need I can add more steps in between the integrals. @ Peter Kravchuk

Comment: It's because you incorrectly evaluated the contour integral. Recall from Jordan's lemma that you must close integrals of the form $f(z) e^{i k z}$ in the upper-half plane, while you must close integrals of the form $f(z) e^{-i k z}$ in the lower-half plane. For you, this mean that you pick up a pole with residue $+E_{\vec{p}}$ or $-E_{\vec{p}}$ depending on whether $x^0 - y^0$ is positive or negative. The details are readily available in any QFT textbook -- I recommend chapter 2 of Peskin and Schroeder.

Comment: Please refer Eq 2.50 and 2.58 of Peskin and Shroeder@ Zack

Comment: I made a small edit and make the question as Feynman propagator's particular case such that  $x^0>y^0$, could you please tell now how the virtual particles associated with the above propagator be off-shell? @ Zack

Comment: Nice to see another user from Kerela :)

Comment: Where you from @ Buraian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The propagator I mention is for free theory. Free particles are always on the shell. We can neither create free particles nor detect them because both processes require interaction. In other words, the propagator in my question is an asymptotic particle that is on-shell. So integral only has an on-shell contribution. Virtual particles arise in interacting theories, where momenta of virtual particles away from mass-shell contributes to the propagator. More mathematically, the momenta that we are integrating over appears in more than one propagator, so if by contour integration we choose an on-shell pole from one propagator, the other won’t be.

Answer (score 0):

> The propagator I mention is for free theory. Free particles are always on the shell. We can neither create free particles nor detect them because both processes require interaction.

It is a common misunderstanding; a free particle is by definition a real particle in a weak external field - so weak that the kinetic term dominates the other ones in the particle equation.

If you imply really non interacting particles, you may not write any equation for them nor assign specific properties like masses, spins, shapes, whatever.

A virtual particle is a retarded (or not) solution that gets into equation written for another particle. A Coulomb field is a virtual patricle of this sort.

A propagator is an intermediate part of calculations; it has no other meaning.